# inline function redefinition linking error

Tags: c++

I got a class exported in dll. And got inline functions in that exported class:

Header.h

```
class MODULE_EXPORT A
{
 public:
    int GetInt(){ return iSomeInt; }
};
```

When I include that header file in a seperate module. I Got error LNK2005 which means:  GetInt() already defined.

If I put the function definition in .cpp file . NO error occurs.

GetInt is inline function if I define it that way in the header file ,right?  so why the redefinition linking error?  I use the vc++ compiler. (Visual Studio 2010).

EDIT:

```
#pragma  once
```

has already been added to the header file. Forgot to mention that.

Comment: You shouldn't export an inlined function, should you ?

Comment: well, that's the point. Inspiring! @YvesDaoust

Comment: If you tag the class as exported, every .cpp that includes the class definition will generate a copy of the method. Two problems: the linker will complain, and the function might not be inlined ! Abstain from exporting the method.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially for a function definition in a header file is visible to every compilation unit and they attempt to compile it.

However the function is already defined in the dll.

The solution would be place the definition in the cpp file as you noted or to use the static keyword so the definition is only visible to the compilation unit it's defined in and not ones that include it.

Also inlining functions is only a performance hint for the compiler, it may not inline it. And for this function I can't imagine their being any performance benefits given it's simplicity so I'd recommend moving it into the .cpp file.

Comment: Your part about inlining not being a benefit is bogus. Inlining in this case is a guaranteed win - the function call overhead would be much greater than a plain int assignment.

Comment: gcc and msvcc will automatically inline simple functions like this, either if they are in the header (compiler inlining) or in the cpp (the linker can inline). So explicitly thinking about inlining for performance seems a bit moot IMO.

Comment: Will MSVC inline a function from a DLL at runtime-link time? Your post essentially says "inlining small/simple functions is not a benefit".

Comment: It's my understanding that the Link-Time Code Generator in MSVC provides definitions of which functions can be inlined in the dll. And I meant to say that the benefits are negligible - which to my understanding they usually are (ignoring potentially deep inheritances and virtual functions etc)

Comment: That's not dynamic linking, that's when you're producing a final exe/dll. MSVC isn't there during dynamic (runtime) linking.

Comment: _"Also inlining functions is only a performance hint for the compiler, it may not inline it"_ While true in the main, the `inline` keyword is not being used here. The point is that the function is _guaranteed_ to have the relevant linkage semantics, which makes at least half of your answer wrong.